# Best practices for updating passwords on a large number of machines running Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, password

I'm going through the process of updating passwords on a dozen or so machines running Windows Server 2012 over RDP from an Apple keyboard.  I can't press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>DEL</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>END</kbd> because those keys literally do not exist or do not work over RDP.  My current solution is to create a file on each machine containing the following script, running it, then tediously typing in a bunch of really long really painfully unique passwords because the Change Password screen doesn't accept <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> (Paste).

```
set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
objshell.WindowsSecurity
```

Is there a better way?

EDIT: Unfortunately, suggestions that involve overwriting the password (e.g. lusrmgr2.msc -> ... -> Set Password) won't work for this situation because of the potential for losing access to encrypted files, certs, etc.

Comment: On my MacBook Pro, I can use Function + Control + Option (aka Alt) + Backspace to bring up the screen to change my password on Windows 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [A real, physical keyboard](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description=keyboard&N=-1&isNodeId=1).  One that has all the buttons you need would be best.
2. [On-Screen Keyboard (OSK.exe)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/type-without-keyboard#type-without-keyboard=windows-7)
3. [WinRM](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/09/24/an-introduction-to-winrm-basics.aspx) or [PowerShell Remoting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700227.aspx) or [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) - remote CLI interfaces you can use to reset your passwords with.

Comment: #1 Hahaha, right, but lacks paste. #2 Shockingly, OSK doesn't work -- it displays a message box suggesting to use the a physical keyboard instead. #3 Any solution involving setting the password without inputting the original password is a non-starter due to the potential associated data loss.  I'll update the question.

Comment: @davidzarlengo [Set-ADAccountPassword](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617261.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you *can* enter the old and new passwords from the Control Panel on Windows Server 2012, but it requires several steps.  For future reference,

1. RDP into the machine.
2. Press Win-C to bring up the "Charms bar"
3. Click the Start tile to bring up the Start Tiles
4. Open the Control Panel
5. Click "User Accounts"
6. Click "User Accounts" again on the next screen
7. **Click "Manage another account"**
8. Click the account you're logged in with
9. Finally, click "Change the password"

Step 7 was not obvious because of some other elements also on the screen, namely the giant tile that shows the name and picture of the user that is logged in. Using the Charms bar to navigate to the Start Tiles is easier than navigating your mouse onto the 2x2 pixel target in the lower left corner, especially over RDP.